# null pointer on photo upload app for facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook, nullpointerexception

My application that uploads photos to facebook has stopped working and is now force closing. Below is the logcat for when the force close occurs. I am having trouble drilling down where the problem is. Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Full code can be viewed at https://github.com/adamwhiles/EasyPhotoUpload

** Update ** I reverted back to an early version of my app and one I know is working and still having the same issue. I think maybe Facebook changed something. I use other facebook apps that do not rely on SSO and they still seem to be working.

```
07-15 14:33:13.262: W/dalvikvm(636): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
07-15 14:33:13.323: E/AndroidRuntime(636): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 14:33:13.323: E/AndroidRuntime(636): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 14:33:13.323: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at libcore.net.UriCodec.decode(UriCodec.java:149)
07-15 14:33:13.323: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:45)
07-15 14:33:13.323: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:182)
07-15 14:33:13.323: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:751)
07-15 14:33:13.323: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at com.adamwhiles.easyphotoupload.EasyPhotoUpload.uploadImage(EasyPhotoUpload.java:239)
07-15 14:33:13.323: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at com.adamwhiles.easyphotoupload.EasyPhotoUpload.access$5(EasyPhotoUpload.java:233)
07-15 14:33:13.323: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at com.adamwhiles.easyphotoupload.EasyPhotoUpload$2.onClick(EasyPhotoUpload.java:132)
07-15 14:33:13.323: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
07-15 14:33:13.323: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
07-15 14:33:13.323: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-15 14:33:13.323: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-15 14:33:13.323: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-15 14:33:13.323: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-15 14:33:13.323: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 14:33:13.323: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-15 14:33:13.323: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-15 14:33:13.323: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-15 14:33:13.323: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-15 14:33:14.092: I/dalvikvm(636): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-15 14:33:14.252: I/dalvikvm(636): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: Have a take a look on this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143644/null-pointer-exception-when-posting-a-picture-to-facebook-wall-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918660/upload-a-image-contained-in-a-url-to-facebook-in-android

Comment: After looking at your and the facebook sources i'm pretty sure that your access_token is null when you try to upload photos.
This line from the facebook sources is causing the NullPointerException:

    URLDecoder.decode(params.getString("access_token"));

Where params is the bundle you used like this:

    facebook.request("me/photos", params, "POST");

Maybe you should use the DialogListener to check if your login really worked before using the access_token.

Comment: @Weeman So if the login didnt work then the access token will be null correct? I will check this when im back home...thanks.. some older versions of my app work on gingerbread but when i run it on ics it gives the same error...not sure how to explain that.

Comment: @adamwhiles yes, thats my guess.